# SSD drives lifetime

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, msata, mtbf

Some years ago when I was looking to buy an SSD drive, I remember reading about how SSD drives had low lifetime with frequent read/writes, so I backed off.

Now I see this in Specifications:
http://www.kingston.com/en/ssd/s#sms200s3
MTTF: 1,000,000 Hrs

That's 114 years (ok, it could be a few years less, but still WOW)

What has changed since then?
What is your personal experience about this technology?

Comment: Better wear leveling, both in hardware and software, as well as some improvements in the materials that are storing the bits.  Larger capacities also generally mean there'll be more wear leveling.

Comment: @ernie. Do you own an SSD? If yes for how long?

Comment: The hype around SSD wearing out is just that - hype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to much has actually changed with the technology, more so the understanding of it. Yes with a ton of read/writes it will degrade the life of an SSD drive. Which is why you need to make sure some settings on your PC are turned off. (Specifically defrag) However not so much that it'll kill your computer within the lifetime of its use. Even if it dies 3-5 years from now, there will be better SSDs on the market for a lot cheaper than you purchased your SSD.

Personally I've got a 256gb SSD as my OS drive. I couldn't see going back to a platter drive for my operating system, and the handful of programs I have running of it. Running programs, starting up the computer, everything just goes by very quickly compared to a platter drive. The best thing you can give your computer to upgrade how quickly it responds to what you want to do is by installing an SSD.

If you haven't taken the plunge in purchasing an SSD drive. By all means do so now! There are tons of great drives out there for fairly reasonable prices. You should have no excuse as to why you haven't upgraded yet.

Comment: Thanks for answering. How many years do you have this SSD on your PC?

Comment: I've had my SSD for about 3 years now. Runs just as quickly as the day I put it in.